# Show that the image of the complex function $f(z) =\frac{z}{1+|z|}$ is the open disk centered at the origin with radius 1

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to show that the image of the complex function $f(z) =\frac{z}{1+|z|}$ is the open disk centered at the origin with radius 1 and hence that f is a continuous bijection from the complex plane to the open disk.

I know that this is a simple map that will show this but struggle to visualise what the domain and range of this map would be. Any help on understanding this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To start, you might graph $f(r) = r/(1 + |r|)$ for $r$ real. If necessary, make a table of values and plot points.

Answer (score 0):

By $ \mathbb D$ we denote the open unit disc.

It should be clear that $|f(z)|= \frac{|z|}{1+|z|} <1.$ Hence $f( \mathbb C) \subseteq \mathbb D.$

Now let $w \in \mathbb D$ and put $z = \frac{w}{1-|w|}.$ Then sow that $f(z)=w.$ This gives $f( \mathbb C) \supseteq \mathbb D.$